# Using react-native-dialog, how to get Dialog.Input content?

Tags: react-native

```
<Dialog.Container visible={this.state.dialogSendEmailVisible}>
      <Dialog.Title>Password Recovery</Dialog.Title>
      <Dialog.Input label="Email"></Dialog.Input>
      <Dialog.Button label="OK" onPress={this.handleSendEmail} />
 </Dialog.Container>
```

I have this simple dialog, this is being used for password recovery purposes. I am not a FE developer, and I am not finding how can I pass the value typed on Email field to handleSendEmail function. Github and npm pages do not have any example. 
Github page: https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog

PS: This can be a very react native basic feature, but I am not findindg a way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the Dialog Inputs/Button extend React Native's own - then you can call:

```
onSubmitEditing and onChangeText
```

From the docs:

```
onSubmitEditing
```

> Callback that is called when the text input's submit button is
>   pressed. Invalid if multiline={true} is specified.

```
TYPE        REQUIRED
function    No
```

And

```
onChangeText
```

> Callback that is called when the text input's text changes. Changed
>   text is passed as an argument to the callback handler.

```
TYPE        REQUIRED
function    No
```

It means something like below:

```
<Dialog.Input label="Email" 
   onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
   value={this.state.email}
   onSubmitEditing={
       (event) => this.doSomethingWithSubmit(event)
   }
>
</Dialog.Input>
```

**UPDATE**

So I have tested this, and it works as below - side note - I'm using Typescript so just remove the types ( `: string`) etc:

**In Render**

```
return (
        <View>
           <View>
                <Button onPress={this.showDialog}>
                    <Text>Show Dialog</Text>
                </Button>
                <Dialog.Container visible={true}>
                    <Dialog.Title>Password Recovery</Dialog.Title>
                    <Dialog.Input label="Email" onChangeText={(email : string) => this.handleEmail(email)}
                    ></Dialog.Input>
                    <Dialog.Button label="OK" onPress={this.handleSendEmail} />
                </Dialog.Container>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
```

**handleEmail:**

```
private handleEmail = (email : string) => {
    console.log("email");
    console.log(email);
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Example]

**Further**

As a side note of this project, I noticed when I used Live reload - that the Dialog was never re-rendered rather, rendered on top of the old Dialog. I would take this into consideration. Perhaps it was my environment, but everything else worked fine.

Comment: I just tested, that and it is not working. Maybe they do not extend from react native TextInput class.

Comment: Could you include a link to the github page in the post?

Comment: It does extend react-native TextInput as you can see [here](https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-dialog/blob/master/src/Input.js) in line 30+

Comment: So, it must have a way of collecting what is on this Dialog.Input, right?

Comment: I'll build a component with it in, see what I can do - I'll update my post for you when I'm done @sheepCow

Comment: I appreciate that this answer covers everything, but it includes to much information. Quotes from the docs do nothing to answer the question. It is much better when you simply explain it in your own words, because it would make for a shorter answer to the same affect.

Comment: @YungGun - I disagree, it has 2 small relevant quotes and covers code, screenshots 2 snippets from the docs. It was relevant for the OP, also.

Comment: It is relevant, you're right, but I felt it could be more concise. Might be better to include all the info like you did in your answer, though, it could just be my personal preference. @JRK